# Jackson cannot deserialize some non-empty fields

Tags: kotlin, jackson, deserialization

I have a problem with the object deserialization.

My DTO contains a list of Pairs (the previous version was Map).

```
data class MyDto(
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) 
    val myField: List<Pair<String, Boolean>>?
)
```

And I constantly receive a `MissingKotlinParameterException`

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.MissingKotlinParameterException: Instantiation of [simple type, class kotlin.Pair<java.lang.String,java.lang.Boolean>] value failed for JSON property first due to missing (therefore NULL) value for creator parameter first which is a non-nullable type\n at [Source: (io.netty.buffer.ByteBufInputStream); line: 9, column: 33] (through reference chain: my.path.MyDto[\"field\"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->kotlin.Pair[\"first\"])\n\tat org.springframework.http.codec.json.AbstractJackson2Decoder.processException(AbstractJackson2Decoder.java:162)
```

my json looks like:

```
{
   "myField" : [
      "A": true,
      "B": false
   ]
}
```

As you can see I have already made the list nullable and put an annotation`@JsonIgnoreProperties`. But still I get the error.

My configuration for the objectMapper

```
@Bean
@Primary
fun objectMapper(): ObjectMapper = jacksonObjectMapper().apply {
   findAndRegisterModules()

   .disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
   .disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DURATIONS_AS_TIMESTAMPS)

   .disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_IGNORED_PROPERTIES)
   .disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_NULL_CREATOR_PROPERTIES)
   .disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES)
   .disable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_ARRAY_AS_NULL_OBJECT)
   .disable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT)
   .enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY)
   .enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_FLOAT_AS_INT)
}
```

What should I also enable/disable to make it work?

Comment: Your JSON doesn't look quite right. If you try to paste your JSON snippet into some JSON linter (e.g. https://jsonlint.com/) it won't accept it. Should the square brackets be curly brackets? Also, just to clarify: do you want the DTO to be a list of pairs, or a map, or do you not really care which? And, in the JSON the property is called `field`, but in the DTO it's `myField`. Are they basically the same field which you're trying to connect?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
List<Pair<String, Boolean>>
```

with

```
Map<String, Boolean>
```

And change the JSON to:

```
{
   "myField" : {
      "A": true,
      "B": false
   }
}
```

Should work as intended now.